# how to use UITableViews for multiple datasets

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview, nsindexpath

I am currently playing around with a navigational based app. Where I want to allow the user to construct a search query by selecting one of several different uitableview cells when touched leads them to a sub uitableview where I will display the data for the user to select.

each cell will load the same subview however it will load it with different datasets. I am wanting to know an appropriate way of handling the transition of data (when the user selects the cell from the subveiw how can I control which cell that data should be sent back to?

I am thinking about passing the subview the Indexpath of the mainviews selected cell.. then passing it back to when the subview is poped from the stack so that it knows where the data needs to be.. is that the best solution? or is their another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, give the subview a property for the indexPath of main view's selected cell.  Set this property in the main view's didSelectCell method before pushing the subview.

Once you pass that indexPath back to the main view with you data, you can use

```
[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

to access the correct cell.